# Reducing an array of strings into individual strings using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to reduce an array of strings into individual strings, it works well only if i have one string within each array, but not more than one.

```
const listItems = [
  {
    sys: {
      type: 'Link',
      linkType: 'Entry',
      id: 'm-list-basic-1'
    }
  },
  {
    sys: {
      type: 'Link',
      linkType: 'Entry',
      id: 'm-list-basic-2'
    }
  },
  {
    sys: {
      type: 'Link',
      linkType: 'Entry',
      id: 'm-list-basic-3'
    }
  }
];

const listIds = listItems.reduce((a, currentValue) =>
            [...a, currentValue.sys.id], [])

// I have also tried `mlistId.toString()`
console.log(...listIds)
```

Currently i get, for example:

`m-list-basic-1 m-list-basic-2 m-list-basic-3` (all on the same line using spread)

`m-list-basic-1,m-list-basic-2,m-list-basic-3` (comma'ed using `toString()`

whereas i want them individual like so:

`m-list-basic-1`

`m-list-basic-2`

`m-list-basic-3`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You are trying to console.log mlistId, but I don't see a variable with that name anywhere? I assume you are trying to console.log listIds

Comment: Yup, correct and I am trying to return individual strings

Comment: this looks ok to me (although it would be simpler to understand using `map` rather than `reduce`). Can you show both the output you want to obtain, and what you actually get, so we can see the problem?

Comment: Thanks, i left an example of the console log

Comment: So, this is _really_ about printing something into the console??

Comment: you wanna new line ? just add \n

Answer (score 1):

Try with `forEach`:

```js
const listItems = [
  {
    sys: {
      type: 'Link',
      linkType: 'Entry',
      id: 'm-list-basic-1'
    }
  },
  {
    sys: {
      type: 'Link',
      linkType: 'Entry',
      id: 'm-list-basic-2'
    }
  },
  {
    sys: {
      type: 'Link',
      linkType: 'Entry',
      id: 'm-list-basic-3'
    }
  }
];

const listIds = listItems.reduce((a, currentValue) =>
            [...a, currentValue.sys.id], [])

listIds.forEach(l => console.log(l))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to print the `id` as a new line separated string, you don't need reduce to do this. Instead, you want to use `Array.map`, combined with `String.join` with a `\n` character.

See example below:

```js
const listItems = [
  {
    sys: {
      type: 'Link',
      linkType: 'Entry',
      id: 'm-list-basic-1'
    }
  },
  {
    sys: {
      type: 'Link',
      linkType: 'Entry',
      id: 'm-list-basic-2'
    }
  },
  {
    sys: {
      type: 'Link',
      linkType: 'Entry',
      id: 'm-list-basic-3'
    }
  }
];

console.log(listItems.map(item => item.sys.id).join('\n'));
```